# Re-numbering a list based on changing criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, ranking, leaderboard

newbie to the site. I have searched various wordings of what I am looking to do to no avail. Hopefully someone can provide some assistance as I may just be over thinking it.

I have a spreadsheet where I track various data points for a specific sport. There is a Leaderboard that updates weekly provided by the sports org. At the end of each season, x amount of people earn a "bid" to a championship based on their placements in the overall standings. There are 4 seasons in a year. Also throughout the year, there are other various methods to "earn a bid". There is an order and once a player has earned a "bid", they are no longer considered for additional bids for the rest of the sport year.

I have an example spreadsheet attached here that has some sample data.
It has the Global standings for each of the players, their ID's, score, region and their in region ranking as well as global ranking. At the other end of the spreadsheet are the 5 ways to "earn a bid". Each time a bid is earned, the regional and global standings have to be "re-ranked" (if #1 globally wins a bid then #2 becomes #1, etc,). 1st, they are re-ranked REGIONALLY after the 1st bid is won. 2nd, they are re-ranked GLOBALLY and then GLOBALLY again for the remaining 3 bid types.

For the life of me, I can not figure out how to re-rank after each bid is awarded, thus moving all other players UP in both Regional and Global rankings where required. Its not always as easy as #2 becomes #1, #5 becomes #4.. sometimes its as drastic as #13 becomes #2 depending on who won bids and how throughout the season/year.

I have a pretty complicated spreadsheet in real life with multiple tabs and some pretty crazy formulas and links to other databases but can not seem to tackle this what-seems-to-be an easy task in comparison. Maybe my brain just hurts. I am currently manually updating the re-rankings by sorting by region, filling in the gaps, re-sorting back to globally and then re-ranking again based on the bids one. it is TE-DI-OUS!

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Here is my notated sample data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P3QsFIIScDyIQhx6E27jv7WlGP_GoZ-_jU8WrKHrBk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you are populating sheet rows with a DB query, you might want to fix it in the ORDER BY.

Comment: So essentially you'd like to reorder automatically the columns with red "Global re-rank"?

Comment: Yes, so the rank as you see them in the example, I have manually entered after putting the "x" in the bid columns. I am looking for a way to automatically renumber the ranks ignoring the ones with a bid.